# Get Department for current user using REST API (Javascript)

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

Is it possible to get the department of the current user using REST API (Javascript)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.. Try the following request:

`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Department`

If this doesn't work you might need to use the following:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Department')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'`

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Department')?@v='domain\username'`

Reference:

[SharePoint 2013: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: Thank you @Arsalan... I was killing myself on this, the thing is that it seems that the property is not configured in my server

Comment: how about current user? without passing @v parameter

Comment: `http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` This call will give you all properties for current user.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without passing @v parameter:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.UserProfileProperties.results.length; i++) {
            switch (data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Key) {
                case "Department":
                    alert(data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```