# How to Parse GetMyProperties REST Response

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, api

This is what the pre-parsed data looks like in the console after querying

`http://mysharepointsite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Department` :

[image]

---

I am trying to get the department of the current user and I am having a lot of difficulty.

I am currently at a stage where I am trying to copy [this SE question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141983/get-department-for-current-user-using-rest-api-javascript), and I managed to at least get somewhere by running this in PowerShell:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest http://mysharepointsite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Department -UseDefaultCredentials
$response.Content
```

Where `Content` does in fact contain my department (IT), but it is hidden in a load of xml data which I don't need.

I have no idea how to get just the department name using javascript, but this is the code I have at the moment (which is being executed from a content editor web part):

```
function getUser() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

    var requestUri = "http://mysharepointsite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    }); 

    function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var x = data.department;
        alert(x);
    } 
    function onError(error) {
        alert("Error on retrieving current user.");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getUser();
});
```

Where in this case, I just get an alert which says `undefined`. Can anyone please help me understand how to parse this incoming data?

Comment: @GintasK Hi Ginta - I am getting a `Invalid character` error when this line runs : `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: There can be 2 things then: the json object is not formed correctly (which I doubt) or the data is parsed already. try using your old code but add console.log(data); and see what your request returns :)

Comment: @GintasK Okay I added an image of what `console.log(data);` looks like in the console... it is pretty confusing - I have no idea what to do with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
var x = data.department;
alert(x);
```

with

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data); 
var x = parsedData.department; 
alert(x);
```

you can also add

```
console.log(parsedData);
```

so you can see inside the returned object in your browser's console :)

**UPDATE:**

You might need to modify your request url to

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Department
```

According to [this article](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: @Bassie see my updated answer :)