# percentage completeness of sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

can we show the Completion percentage of  Profile in sharepoint 2013 ? for example if doesnot have photo or donot complete personal information or either if donot fill expertise or hobbies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some Apps in the Store that do it.

- https://store.office.com/search.aspx?qu=profile

You can do it yourself by calling the `_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` REST endpoint and verifying all properties and make up a percentage

- [How to Parse GetMyProperties REST Response](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181718/how-to-parse-getmyproperties-rest-response)
- http://blog.jussipalo.com/2016/08/sharepoint-spuserprofilespeoplemanager.html
- https://tesitgeek.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/how-to-get-sharepoint-2013-user-profile-properties-using-rest-api/
- http://sharepointcookies.com/2016/04/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user-profiles-and-local-storage/